# base64 image decoding intermittently reporting 1x1 dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, base64

Using ie9/ie10, I am trying to detect the dimensions of a base64 image.  My code works in the other current browsers.  These are the steps I follow:

1. ajax down a base64 string,
2. create a new Image() object,
3. set the base64 string as the src,
4. use imagesloaded OR wait for the onload event

Moments later arrives a successful loaded callback, but... the image dimensions are reported as 1x1.  Sometimes.  Other times it works just fine.

So... how do I detect when the image is... decoded?  Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Do you have some code that you can show us, perhaps a jsfiddle of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `onload` callback. Your image is not downloaded yet when you first try to get its size.
That is why you get wrong size.

```
image.onload = function () {
  console.log(this.width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **naturalWidth** instead of **width**. 
It works for me in Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the two? Please elaborate.